# Python 2.7 qrequests.map on separate thread gets response but grequests.send does not

Tags: python-2.7, grequests

I have a python program that creates a separate process for a HttpServer to run on. Then I make a request to that [HttpServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html) using [grequests.map](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/blob/master/grequests.py) on a separate thread or [grequests.send](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/blob/master/grequests.py) with a [threading.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

When I use `grequests.map` on a separate thread I get a response. However, when I use `grequests.send` using a `threading.Pool` I do not get a response.

I have pasted the code below that demonstrates the issue I am having. Why is it that `grequests.map` on a separate thread works, but `grequests.send` with a `threading.Pool` does not?

Using `grequest.send` with a `threading.Pool` results in the following output:

```
[07-19 09:43:26] p99437
{/Users/mhoggan/Development/test_rest/test_request_handler.py:48} INFO - Making requst to endpoint=http://localhost:8081/test/
[07-19 09:43:26] p99437 {/Users/mhoggan/Development/test_rest/request_handler.py:64} INFO - <grequests.send was called...>
[07-19 09:43:26] p99437 {/Users/mhoggan/Development/test_rest/test_request_handler.py:54} INFO - Waiting for response...
[07-19 09:43:31] p99437 {/Users/mhoggan/Development/test_rest/test_request_handler.py:59} CRITICAL - Failed to make request with error <type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>:.
[07-19 09:43:31] p99437 {/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:212} DEBUG - Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
```

=========================================================================

Using `grequests.map` on a separate thread results in the following output:

```
[07-19 09:47:20] p99528 {/Users/mhoggan/Development/test_rest/test_request_handler.py:48} INFO - Making requst to endpoint=http://localhost:8081/test/
[07-19 09:47:20] p99528 {/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:212} DEBUG - Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jul/2017 09:47:20] "GET /test/?token=test HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[07-19 09:47:20] p99528 {/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:400} DEBUG - http://localhost:8081 "GET /test/?token=test HTTP/1.1" 200 None
[07-19 09:47:20] p99528 {/Users/mhoggan/Development/test_rest/test_request_handler.py:25} INFO - Status code on valid request is 200 content=<html>
  <head>
    <title>Data.</title>
  </head>
  <body><p>This is a test.</p>
    <p>You accessed path: /test/</p>
    <p>With params: {'token': ['test']}</p>
  </body>
</html>

[07-19 09:47:20] p99528 {/Users/mhoggan/Development/test_rest/request_handler.py:62} INFO - <grequests.map was called...>
[07-19 09:47:20] p99528 {/Users/mhoggan/Development/test_rest/test_request_handler.py:54} INFO - Waiting for response...
```

=========================================================================

```
import grequests
import logging
import threading

from gevent.pool import Pool


logging.basicConfig(format='[%(asctime)s] p%(process)s {%(pathname)s:'
                           '%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class RequestHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, endpoint_url):
        self.endpoint_url = endpoint_url
        if not self.endpoint_url.startswith("http://"):
            self.endpoint_url = "http://{0}".format(self.endpoint_url)

    @staticmethod
    def _threaded_map(
        request,
        response_callback,
        error_callback=None,
        timeout=None
    ):
        grequests.map(
            [request],
            exception_handler=error_callback,
            size=1
        )

    def request_for_test(
        self,
        response_callback,
        error_callback=None,
        timeout=None
    ):
        header = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
        payload = {'token': 'test'}

        if not error_callback:
            error_callback = self.request_exception
        request = grequests.get(
            self.endpoint_url,
            headers=header,
            params=payload,
            timeout=timeout,
            hooks={'response': [response_callback]},
        )
        args = (request, response_callback, error_callback, timeout,)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self._threaded_map, args=args)
        thread.run()
        logger.info('<grequests.map was called...>')
        #grequests.send(request, pool=Pool(2), stream=False)
        #logger.info('<grequests.send was called...>')
```

=========================================================================

```
import logging
import s2sphere
import threading
import unittest2

from request_handler import RequestHandler
from test_service import (
    TestService,
    END_POINT_0,
    HOST_NAME,
    PORT,
)


logging.basicConfig(format='[%(asctime)s] p%(process)s {%(pathname)s:'
                           '%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def _handle_valid_request(response, **kwargs):
    logger.info('Status code on valid request is {0} content={1}'.format(
            response.status_code,
            response.content
        )
    )
    event.set()


def _handle_error(request, exception):
    logger.error('Failing the tests due to request error: '
                 '{0} -- in request {1}'.format(exception, request))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 5  # In seconds
    httpd = TestService()
    httpd.start()
    event = threading.Event()
    endpoint_url = 'http://{0}:{1}{2}'.format(
        HOST_NAME,
        PORT,
        END_POINT_0
    )

    rh = RequestHandler(endpoint_url=endpoint_url)
    try:
        logger.info('Making requst to endpoint={0}'.format(endpoint_url))
        rh.request_for_test(
            _handle_valid_request,
            error_callback=_handle_error,
            timeout=REQUEST_TIMEOUT
        )
        logger.info('Waiting for response...'.format(endpoint_url))
        assert(event.wait(timeout=REQUEST_TIMEOUT))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.fatal('Failed to make request with error {0}:{1}.'.format(
                type(e),
                e
            )
        )
    finally:
        httpd.stop()
```

=========================================================================

```
import multiprocessing

from BaseHTTPServer import (
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler,
    HTTPServer,
)
from urlparse import (
    urlparse,
    parse_qs
)


END_POINT_0 = '/test/'
HOST_NAME = 'localhost'
PORT = 8081


class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        url_path = urlparse(self.path).path
        url_query = urlparse(self.path).query
        url_params= parse_qs(url_query)

        if url_path == END_POINT_0 or url_path == END_POINT_1:
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(
                '<html>\n'
                '  <head>\n'
                '    <title>Data.</title>\n'
                '  </head>\n'
                '  <body><p>This is a test.</p>\n'
                '    <p>You accessed path: %s</p>\n'
                '    <p>With params: %s</p>\n'
                '  </body>\n'
                '</html>\n' % (url_path, url_params)
            )


class TestService(object):

    def __init__(self, server_class=HTTPServer):
        self.httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT), Handler)
        self.server_process = None

    def _start(self):
        self.server_process.daemon = True
        self.httpd.serve_forever()

    def start(self):
        self.stop()

        if not self.server_process or not self.server_process.is_alive():
            self.server_process = multiprocessing.Process(
                target=self._start
            )
        self.server_process.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.server_process:
            self.httpd.server_close()
            self.server_process.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that grequests.send uses gevent under the hood in a manner such that the call back is called on the same thread that the send was called from. Thus using the threading.Event to block on the thread prevents the response callback from being called until after the thread.Event is signaled.